# jquery - hide not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

By clicking on "empty cart?", I am unsetting the cart array which is working fine. Now I wanted another form to be hidden if this "empty cart" button is clicked.

html:

```
<form id="f1" action="checkout.php" method="post">
    <input name="cust_login" type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>    
<br>
<button><a href = "cart.php?cmd=emptycart">empty cart?</a></button>
```

javascript:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
        $("#f1").hide();
     });
 });
 </script>
```

php code for unsetting array:

```
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
 unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
```

But hide is not working here.

My question is, can we use button and link together as I have written ? If not, then how to implement it?

Comment: The problem is you are refreshing the page.... which will revert any changes done by javacript in the client side

Comment: This isn't valid HTML markup

Comment: how it can be resolved

Comment: Can you not check whether the cart is empty when you load the page and hide or show the form at that point?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cmd = '<?php echo $_GET["cmd"] ;?>' ;
  if(cmd == "emptycart")
  {
     $("#f1").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="f1" 
      action="checkout.php" 
      style="<?= (isset($_SESSION['cart_array']) && count($_SESSION['cart_array']))? "display:none;": ""; ?>" 
      method="post">
    <input name="cust_login" type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>    
<br>
<button><a href = "cart.php?cmd=emptycart">empty cart?</a></button>
```

On rendering form - check if cart is empty - render it on hidden state

But in this case your js code had no sense. So you can add

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', "a[href='cart.php?cmd=emptycart']", function(ev){
       ev.preventDefault();
       $.get($(this).attr('href', function() {
         $("#f1").hide();
       });
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Istead of your js code - this one prevent page reload ( which happens when you click on link ) and send request via AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    $("#f1").attr('style','display: block !important')
  });
 });
```

or to add a class to style file that do the same and then just add this class when clicking on the button.

Comment: May I ask why you go for `.attr('style', '')` rather than `.css('display', 'block')`?

Comment: i'ts stronger. It will be part of the html attributes instead of using jQuery.css which will not be part of the attributes

Comment: Using `css` also adds inline styling. Even then, `show()` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

HTML

```
<form id="f1" action="checkout.php" method="post">
  <input name="cust_login" type="submit" value="Continue" />
  </form>    
<br>
<button>empty cart?</button>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
     //$("#f1").hide();
     window.location.href = "cart.php?cmd=emptycart";
   });
});
```

Comment: This one has no sense - you hide element and than reload page